# Execute nx command using powershell ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I am working on a node based project where it requires me to perform the following operation whenever I try to open my application. Commands are:

```
1. switch to the directory of the existing project using cmd
2. execute cmd-> caddy run
3. open a new cmd window on the same directory/ switch to that directory again
4. execute cmd-> nx serve application-frontend
5. open a new cmd window on the same directory/ switch to that directory again
6. execute cmd-> nx serve application-backend
```

After which I can access my application on the browser. I want to make a PowerShell script .ps1 for this process which I can run to start my application every time without having the need to go through these steps. E.g below.

I am able to shift to my directory with PowerShell but not able to actually start my caddy server and run nx commands. For e.g.

```
Set-Location -Path "path_to_my_application..."
.\caddy.exe
```

Comment: So what happens you try to run your caddy server? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: caddy server will run here because I am trying to execute an .exe file here. But I need to know how run nx commands which are at step 4 and 6

Comment: So what kind of command is `nx`? If it isn't an executable, it can't be expected to be available by default in PowerShell.